# Clang Cannot Find Conversion Operator

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

In the following code clang complains that there exist no conversion operator:

```
class A{
public:
  operator int () const {return i;}

  A(int i_): i(i_) {}

  template<class B>
  friend auto operator * (const B& l, A&& r)
  -> decltype(l * int(std::move(r))){
    return l * int(std::move(r));
  }

  int i;
};
```

This happens with all clang versions 6-9, see https://godbolt.org/z/ELuRHp. The error message is as follows:

```
<source>:11:19: error: cannot convert 'typename std::remove_reference<A &>::type' (aka 'A') to
'int' without a conversion operator
  -> decltype(l * int(std::move(r))){
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The same code compiles with gcc 7-9 just fine, so I'm wondering if this is a bug in clang or maybe the code is not correct.

Edit: A shorter version of the same error, which was provided by @daniel-langr, can be found here https://godbolt.org/z/Krnh27.
The original code example is a simplified version of a class in our code base, hence the unnecessary `decltype`.

Comment: I have checked the code without the decltype, and it compiles. There are two things here that I don't understand, why do you need that decltype, and why do you need A by rvalue reference?

Comment: Simpler member function declaration that generates the same problem: `auto f(A a) -> decltype(int(a));`: [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Krnh27). Another case: `decltype(int(std::declval<A>())) f();`.

Comment: @Kerek This is a simplified version of a class in our code base, that's why there is the decltype and rvalue reference. I know that I don't need the decltype, but I still would like to understand why this doesn't work with clang.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a clang bug.

From [unqualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup):

> **For a name used anywhere in class definition** (including base class specifiers and nested class definitions), except inside a member function body, a default argument of a member function, exception specification of a member function, or default member initializer, where the member may belong to a nested class whose definition is in the body of the enclosing class, **the following scopes are searched:**
>
> **a) the body of the class in which the name is used until the point of use**
>
> ...

According to the above, your user-defined conversion function must be visible in the trailing return type.

Here is another example of a member function which works fine on gcc but does not compile on clang.

```
void f(A a, decltype(int(A)) {}
```

Comment: I also think this is a bug in clang and I've filed a bug report for this ([here](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45372)), but so far there has been no comment from a clang developer.